# Javascript object of arrays syntax

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my syntax. I have this declaration for a javascript object of array:

```
$.fn.eCardify.frames = {
    nonie: {
        {flip_over_envelope, flip_over_envelope},
        {open_envelope, open_envelope},
        {show_card, show_card},
        {open_card, open_card}          
    },
    ie: {
        {flip_over_envelope_ie, flip_over_envelope_ie},
        {open_envelope_ie, open_envelope_ie},
        {show_card_ie, show_card_ie},
        {open_card_ie, open_card_ie}
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to access it this way:

```
function step(){
    if($.fn.eCardify.settings.is_ie){
        $.fn.eCardify.frames.ie[$.fn.eCardify.frame]();
    }else{
        $.fn.eCardify.frames.nonie[$.fn.eCardify.frame]();
    }
    $.fn.eCardify.frame++;
}
```

However, chrome (and probably other browsers) isn't liking my array declaration. It gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` on the second line of the array declaration.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, `{...}` declares an object, not an array.

Comment: `{}` creates an object. `[]` creates an array.

Comment: Thanks guys, figured out I need $.fn.eCardify.frames = { nonie: [

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{}` is for object not array

```
$.fn.eCardify.frames = {
    nonie: [
        [flip_over_envelope, flip_over_envelope],
        [open_envelope, open_envelope],
        [show_card, show_card],
        [open_card, open_card]
    ],
    ie: [
        [flip_over_envelope_ie, flip_over_envelope_ie],
        [open_envelope_ie, open_envelope_ie],
        [show_card_ie, show_card_ie],
        [open_card_ie, open_card_ie]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Arrays use `[]`.

`{}` is for objects (which have key/value pairs)

Answer (score 1):

What you have isn't an array, as the brackets are curly. If you want to declare an array, use square brackets:

```
$.fn.eCardify.frames = {
    nonie: [
        [flip_over_envelope, flip_over_envelope],
        [open_envelope, open_envelope],
        [show_card, show_card],
        [open_card, open_card]          
    ],
    ie: [
        [flip_over_envelope_ie, flip_over_envelope_ie],
        [open_envelope_ie, open_envelope_ie],
        [show_card_ie, show_card_ie],
        [open_card_ie, open_card_ie]
    ]
}
```

Although this structure is still weird. Why do you need something like this?

Comment: It's incomplete code with placeholders, it's frames.nonie[step_function, unstep_function]

Comment: I.e., access is something like this for a step: 
`$.fn.eCardify.frames.nonie[$.fn.eCardify.frame][0]();`
And for an ustep: 
`$.fn.eCardify.frames.nonie[$.fn.eCardify.frame-1][1]();`

Answer (score 0):

Objects are notated like so: `{}`, while Arrays are notated with: `[]`.

One of the differences between the two is that Objects expect a key:value definition, and arrays can be just a set of values.

**Example**

```
var arr = [val1, val2, val3];
var obj = {'key1': val1, 'key2': val2, 'key3': val3};
```